# MKMapView change pins on zoom in

Tags: ios, cocoa, mkmapview

for an app I'm developing, I wold like to start the mapView in world view and have circles (or marked area) with inside the number of point of interest I have in those areas.

For Example I have 100 poi in USA where:

25 in California
25 in Arizona
25 in Utah
25 in Nevada

when the user zoom in California, the circle above california with 25 inside, becomes other circles on cities I have poi. i.e.

10 in Los Angeles
10 in San Francisco
5 in Sacramento

when user zoom again on Los Angeles the circle with 10 inside becomes normal pin point above the coordinates.

more or less like this:

[image]

Any suggestions how to do that?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at

http://revolver.be/blog/mapkit-clustering-with-ios/

or

http://getsuperpin.com

or search the web for "cluster ios map"

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from a very bad headache.